# ArrayList error :cannot find symbol

Tags: java, arraylist

Hello This function should compare the elements of the same index in 2 arrays and swap them if their sum = x ,, 
when i build it i get this error in the 3rd line " error: cannot find symbol" ??

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class eeee{
public static int swapx(ArrayList<Iinteger>a , ArrayList<Integer>b , Integer x)
    { int i , pos , n=0 ; 
        Integer a1 , b1 ; 
        for(i=0 ; i<a.size();i++)   
        {    a1=a.get(i);
                 b1=b.get(i);
                 if(a1+b1==x)
                 {
                    n++;
                 a.set(i,b1);
                 b.set(i,a1);

                 }}
                 return n;

    }
```

Comment: On third line, "ArrayList<Iinteger>a ," (the first argument of swapx) may be "ArrayList<Integer>a ,".  There is extra "i" in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is with `ArrayList<Iinteger> a`. `Iinteger` isn't a valid type, I think you wanted `ArrayList<Integer> a` which uses [`java.lang.Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int swapx(*ArrayList<Integer> a*, ArrayList<Integer> b, Integer x) {
        int i, pos, n = 0;
        Integer a1, b1;
        for (i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            a1 = a.get(i);
            b1 = b.get(i);
            if (a1 + b1 == x) {
                n++;
                a.set(i, b1);
                b.set(i, a1);

            }
        }
        return n;
    }
```